# Generic answers for questions

Tags: discussion

I spent some time looking at [unaswered questions tagged magento](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmagento%5D%20answers:0) on Stackoverflow and I noticed the following:

- off-topic/duplicate questions
- vaguely defined questions
- questions I didn't understand (issues with English language)
- programming questions asked by "developers" with no programming experience
- "How can I do this" type of questions without trying first to solve it themselves
- Specific frontend questions asked by "developers" that didn't at least look at their page with Template Path hints on

These questions will show up in this website and I have the following suggestions:

- We should be able to provide links to resources about basic Magento Development (example: [Magento Knowledgebase](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base), various blogs, and so on);
- If the question is not clearly defined, point them to a guide about how to ask a question (if they have issues with the language, then ecourage them to use images to describe what they want)
- If a Magento programming question is asked by someone with no programming experience, the answer should be: learn how to code first, then we can help you, here are some links/resources

My opinion is that a detailed specific answer doesn't help at all. They will "copy-paste" the answer if someone provides it and that's the end, moving on, next question.

Answer (score 1):

I will just focus my answer to "duplicates".

There is a functionality to **flag** question and provide a link to duplicate question which was answered before. What I see on Stackoverflow is, that even if I flag questions, mods didn't do anything and there were still copy/paste answers provided by users.

On my opinion, we should definitely close a duplicate question and link it to the original one. I would also explicitly write to users (when posting questions) to **use the search** before posting. It would save time for everyone.

I mostly agree with your other opinions.

Comment: Tihs might be easier to see here, if mods know more about Magento!